# Create http header array from string

Tags: apache, http-headers, httpresponse

I'm using apache's **HttpCore** library to implement proxy .
I have headers of response cached as string separated by **'\r\n'** (each key:value).
How can i set a **HttpResponse**'s headers using **setHeaders()** by converting my string to **Header[]** .
I can iterate over the string and parse it using **'\r\n'** and **':'** as delimiters ,
but is there more elegant way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the class `DefaultHttpRequestParser`, though it'd probably be simpler to use the method class `BasicLineParser` for parsing each line instead of counting on the ':' delimiter.

```
    BasicLineParser lineParser = new BasicLineParser();
    for (String line : headers.split("\r\n")) {
        CharArrayBuffer charArrayBuffer = new CharArrayBuffer(line.length());
        charArrayBuffer.append(line);
        Header header = lineParser.parseHeader(charArrayBuffer);
    }
```